# Limpiar valores de un objeto en una lista de c#

Tags: c#, lista, webapi, netcore

Tengo un problema con una lista en una WEBAPI la cual inyecto desde el `Startup.cs` así, `List<Apis> list`

La obtengo desde los controller, la paso a otras clases que la necesitas, obtengo un objeto que cumpla cierta condición y manipulo los datos de este asi.

```
var api = list.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id === 1);

api.texto = "Texto";
```

Pero cuando quiero usar la lista en otra clase que también se pasa a través del controller esta ya viene con el atributo Texto y un valor asignado.

Lo que quiero saber es si hay una forma de que los valores de los atributos que modifique en el objeto en cualquier clase del api no se mantengan durante la ejecución de esta.

Comment: Es  es porque practicamente  to lista  es global, ¿Cuál  sería su ciclo o  tiempo de vida desde que uno le asigno texto? Lo otro ¿no habrá problemas luego de sincronismo? o no hay posibilidad que dos controladores puedan estar modificando el  texto. Ahora si lo borras, como queda el otro lado  si la siguiese usando. Creo que no entiendo bien la pregunta.

Comment: Cómo estás inyectando esa lista, *Scoped*, *Singleton* o *Transient*

Comment: @rene uso Scoped